# Turning off the T-Mobile @Home (USA) router's wi-fi signal

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Has anyone managed to turn off the 802.11 feature of the [T-Mobile @Home router](http://www.t-mobile.com/shop/phones/Cell-Phone-Detail.aspx?cell-phone=T-Mobile-@Home-HiPort-Wireless-Router)? I want to get 2 lines, so the wi-fi-less adapter is out, but I already have fine coverage and don't want an interfering signal.

As a corollary does anyone know if there's a more controllable firmware out there, similar to [openWRT](http://openwrt.org/) which supports this router, while retaining the SIM and phone features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireless Tab -> look for "Wireless Network Mode" -> select disabled.

Should look like this screen: http://ui.linksys.com/files/WRTU54G-TM/1.00.16.Radius/Basic-Wireless-Settings.htm

Re firmware, DD-WRT does not support it: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WRTU54G-TM.
There is one person attempting to get OpenWRT on it,

- http://www.onceking.info/wp/2009/04/11/custom-firmware-for-t-mobile-hiport-router-wrtu54g-tm-with-ssh-wget-and-rt61/
- http://www.onceking.info/wp/2009/04/12/porting-openwrt-to-wrtu-54g/

, but I have no idea if it will retain those SIM features.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the model. It looks like it has it's own entry in the http://linksysbycisco.com/gpl page. Then so the devices themselves should be able to find support. The user-land device configuration and t-mobile voip behavior might be non-gpl, and may need to get ripped off a working device.

Comment: Oh, and http://ui.linksys.com/ is nifty. while linksysbycisco.com is not.